# How to get access to the calendars on a Android phone?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I gave some tries to access the calendars on a Android phone, but none of my code worked, is there someone that knows for sure, how to **read/query** the calendar events for a specified time range?

Comment: I am using Android phones with Android >4.0

Comment: Do you want events or just open the calander.

Comment: Fire an intent to open Calendar.
 You can follow the below [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373074/how-to-launch-android-calendar-application-using-intent-froyo

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-adding-events-to-the-users-calendar--mobile-8363 you can see this link very self explanable.

Comment: thanks i will have a look at these links

Comment: can i post this as answer so if it work you can accept.

Comment: @piyush the answer you supported had only information about adding a new event, but not reading the events, i need to read the events of a given calendar id

Comment: @anand i want to read/query the calendars, i want the events of a calendar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130025/cannot-read-recurring-events-from-android-calendar-programmatically use this link then

Comment: @piyush Thanks, that is good, but this does not work for the URI events/when

Comment: DOWNVOTERS: please don't downvote by pure hatred

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String[] projection = new String[] { CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION };

// 0 = January, 1 = February, ...

Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
startTime.set(2014,00,01,00,00);

Calendar endTime= Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2015,00,01,00,00);

// the range is all data from 2014

String selection = "(( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + startTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= " + endTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ))";

Cursor cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query( CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null );

// output the events 

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Toast.makeText( this.getApplicationContext(), "Title: " + cursor.getString(1) + " Start-Time: " + (new Date(cursor.getLong(3))).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    } while ( cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: found the solution, this is by way the best answer ever made to this question

Comment: Finally one solution!

Comment: cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fourever.autogreetingapp/fourever.autogreetingapp.mainclasses.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 from ProcessRecord{5368732 14892:fourever.autogreetingapp/u0a181} (pid=14892, uid=10181) requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR                                                                                                                                                                     Both permission is given.

Comment: @akhilbatlawala this code works not on all Android versions, there are at least two different ways to access Calender (events) data, the version I use is for all older Android versions up to Android 4 I think but works also on Android 5. Please have a look on your permissions again, maybe you need more permissions. I unfortunately dont have the application code anymore.